# How can I make Notepad++ default program for `.txt` files?

Tags: windows-10, file-association

I would like `.txt` files to open with Notepad++ by default in Windows 10. I have found the options to change file associations but there is no option to specify custom programs. Here's a screen shot:

[image]

How can I make Notepad++ default program for `.txt` files?

Comment: Are you sure that Notepad++ has been installed using `setup.exe` and was not just extracted from .zip archive which is a.k.a. "portable installation" ?  

You can associate file type _only_ to the applications installed using setup.exe

Comment: @maoizm I use portable versions of Notepad++ and I have no problems associating it as the default for .html, .css, .js, etc. filetypes

Comment: @InterLinked well, thanks, this is really helpful as I use a lot of portables and for sure last time I tried it didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSMS wont give up file associations](https://superuser.com/questions/1373310/ssms-wont-give-up-file-associations)

Comment: @maoizm Not true, you can associate with any .exe you can point to. I have done so and continue to do so on occasion.

Comment: Good News !!!. Finally it worked in Windows 10.

Step 1) Follow David answer to open .txt file notepad Plus.
Step 2) Rename your file as .txt
Step 3) Double click your file, it automatically opens in Notepad++.

Please UPVOTE if this works for you also.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Follow the below steps

1. Right click any .txt file and click

> Open With > > Choose another app

2. In the opened window click

> More Apps

[image]

3. Scroll to bottom and click

> Look for anther app on this PC
>   [image]

4. Navigate to install location of Notepad++. Default is

> C:\Program Files\Notepad++

5. And select "Notepad++.exe"

Comment: Its strange that you can't do this through the settings panel. Seems like a mistake to me... Thanks for the info.

Comment: Just don't work, it changes back to notepad immediately.

Comment: I had to install Notepad++ Fork from Windows 10 store:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/notepad-fork/9plhc123mqwt
to make all mentioned methods work:/

Comment: Sadly, it only works for _most_ - but not all - files. I can, for example, not re-associate *.log files. Which is incredibly annoying...

Comment: I'm trying to set vim as my default editor for .txt files. I've been using this exact method for ages, but for some reason it seems to be broken on 17134 of Win10.

Comment: Unfortunately, the above tip only works when you have installed Notepad++ by downloading it from the web site and installing it explicitly. When you have installed it as an App via the "Look for more Apps in the Store" previously, it will be installed to some other location (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps) that is not accessible via "Look for another App on this PC".

Comment: There are several ways to select Notepad++, but only this way you get the checkbox "always use this app". Windows is like a game . . .

Answer (score 40):

#### How can I make notepad++ default program for .txt files?

1. Run Notepad++ as an Adminstrator
2. Menu > Settings to open the "Preferences" dialog

   - Click "File Association"
   - Click "Notepad", then
   - Click ".txt". then
   - Click "->" to register notepad++ as the program to edit `.txt` files:
   - Click "Close"

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work in Windows 10. Not sure why.

Comment: @EUserNameError You have to run as Admin. Answer updated.

Comment: Tried that. Doing so even prompts the other non-admin users if they want to update their file association. But the very first time that non-admin user visits the Preferences dialog box, his/her choice gets null and void. And I really hate being called by each of the 133 computer users when they want their admin to update their file association, especially when it is to no avail. So a -1 for needing admin privileges.

Comment: YES. For some reason, even though I performed the steps of the other answers, my computer just wouldn't let me set the default app to notepad until I did your method.

Comment: This type of configuration should never be done on an app-specific level, always on an OS level. The top answer gets this right.

Comment: @pzkpfw - Which answer is the "top" answer.  Please note I am pointing out that the order of the answers is dynamic, so really your comment, shouldn't be submitted under this answer but instead upvote the correct answer.

Comment: Unlike the chosen answer, this one actually works! I'm betting this got broken in a Windows 10 update, because I always used to open txt files with notepad++.

Comment: @pzkpfw - while true in general, something in a recent windows update appears to have broken the "normal" OS methods, for some users (including me). Hence this answer is a useful alternative.

Comment: Didn't work for me (windows 7)

Comment: @ashleedawg Well it works for me. That's why I wrote the answer. And I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: Had to login so I could thank you because this was getting me upset that I wouldn't be able to make my files to open with Notepad++ by default, but your solution worked. I found it from [this](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/4984) open issue which mentioned your fix.

Answer (score 26):

With Windows 10 (Oct 2018) this worked for me:

- Open Notepad++ as an administrator and then follow the steps posted by DavidPostill above

then

- Go through the normal Windows process of right click "Open With >" > "Choose another app" and click the "Always use this app to open .txt file" box.

Comment: this worked for me. Double clicking on the file in Windows Explorer works as well instead of "Open With".

Comment: only this worked for me (**WINDOWS 10**)

Comment: As of 12/4/2018 this method worked.  One part or the other did not on its own, but together it did the trick.  I'm guessing the most recent Windows update broke the Default Apps thing, which is kind of obnoxious.  **NOTE:** Once the steps are done, your txt files should take on the Notepad++ icon, so you don't actually have to run n++ as admin again after you're finished.

Comment: There is a file association issue that exists in Windows 10 April 2018 Update and Windows 10 October 2018 Update. Which has been [fixed](https://superuser.com/questions/1373310/ssms-wont-give-up-file-associations/1374236#1374236), the solution is simple, update your system.

Comment: You genious! Thanx

Answer (score 5):

This took me a minute, but this should help.

1. Find a .txt file
2. Right click it
3. Select "Open with..." --> "Choose another app"
4. Scroll down and select "More Apps" on the popup
5. Select "Look for another app on this PC..."
6. Find and select notepad++.exe

Answer (score 4):

If nothing of the above works, try using this:

https://www.binaryfortress.com/NotepadReplacer/

and then Right click on the file > Open With > Choose another app and select Notepad++

Answer (score -1):

Okay, here is a work around:

1. Create a dummy file with the extension you wish to default to your program. The file can be empty.
2. Right click on the dummy file and select Properties.
3. On the General tab there is a section that states:
   Type of file: 
   Opens with  and a button that says .
   Click Change.
4. How do you want to open  files from now on? Choose .
5. Scroll to the bottom and select 
   Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++ and select  and select
6. Close Properties and your done!

Credits to Kent Lasley from : https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/13051/set-notepad-as-default-app-in-windows-10

Comment: @SherylHohman - There is a file association issue that exists in Windows 10 April 2018 Update and Windows 10 October 2018 Update. Which has been [fixed](https://superuser.com/questions/1373310/ssms-wont-give-up-file-associations/1374236#1374236), the solution is simple, update your system.