# `.TXT` file association to Notepad++ "stopped working"

Tags: windows-7, windows, notepad++, text-editors, file-association

I recently formatted and then reinstalled everything, but oddly now, **Windows 7 refuses to let me set Notepad++ as the default `.TXT` editor.**

I try to set the "open with" file as usual:

- right click a `.TXT` file
- `Open With...` → `Choose Default` → <kbd>Browse</kbd>
- paste `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"`

... but Notepad++ *doesn't* show up in the dialog (image below), and the file instead opens with lame old `Notepad.exe`.

[image: img]

**However** when I open `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"` from the <kbd>![Windows Key][oldwinlogo]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> Run dialog, **Notepad++ opens without a problem.**

Also, certain files' context menu have `Edit with Notepad++`, which also works fine.

> From my registry, in case it's relevant:
>
> ```
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]
>   Default="txtfile"
>   Content Type="text/plain"
>   PerceivedType="text"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\PersistentHandler]
>   @="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew]
>   ItemName="@%SystemRoot%\system32\notepad.exe,-470"  
>   NullFile=""
> ```

I tried rebooting... Any ideas?

**Edit:** I had also tried the editing the Associations directly in NPP as admin, without success. Note that I'm using Windows 7.

(I *just* got all my N++ setting/themes/plugins/ftp/etc all painstakingly setup, and it was working fine until I tried it this morning, so I'm hoping for a fix *other* than reinstalling N++.)

Comment: What happens when you try to browse to that location?

Comment: In an open cmd window, does `assoc .txt` return `.txt=txtfile` and `ftype txtfile` return `txtfile=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1` ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - no difference browsing or pasting.

Comment: @LotPings - correct.  `assoc .txt` = `.txt=txtfile`, `ftype txtfile` = `txtfile=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1`

Comment: @DavidPostill - **Not a duplicate** - I'm using Windows 7, and plus I had already tried [your answer](https://superuser.com/a/1324371/774713) to the other question (NPP file assoc as admin) without success.

Comment: Sometimes, Windows registry messes up the executable path/name. I would suggest that you copy `notepad++.exe` and paste it in the same directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\)`. Rename it as something else, for example, `notepad_plus.exe`. Now try to `Open with` and browse to this location. You should be able to see the `new executable`. Let me know if it works.