# can't change associated app for file (from Property) to Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I don't know, even after reinstalling the Windows the same happens - I can't change  the associated program from `right click > Properties` when I want to change that to `Notepad++` (for others, it works).

Even after I click "OK", it still doesn't work (is not changed):

[image]

Any known bugs for this?

Comment: Try [David's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1324367/how-can-i-make-notepad-default-program-for-txt-files/1324371#1324371) on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1324367/how-can-i-make-notepad-default-program-for-txt-files/1324371#1324371).

Comment: @n8te thanks ! one answer there (opening with ADMIN) worked !